# How to set flume configuration from terminal in cloudera?

Tags: bash, apache, hadoop, cloudera, flume

[image: Cloudera Flume User Interface]

I have uploaded the flume UI of cloudera. We can set the Agent Name and paste the contents of flume.conf there, with the help of this UI. I want to do this task from terminal. My flume.conf file is ready. So how to set agent name and flume configuration from terminal using some command?

Thanks..

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for doing this? I was looking for something similar (command line or API for automation).  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no specic commands for modifying a Flume configuration file. This must be manually done, by opening the file and editing it.

Being said that, you can use standard Linux commands in a smart way for modifying the file. An example can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123695/editing-a-java-properties-file-with-bash). In that case, the user wanted to change the value of a `file.input` property without changing other properties nor any commented property with the same name. The community suggested him to use the `sed` command in this way:

```
NEW=/new/name    
sed -i 's:^[ \t]*file.input[ \t]*=\([ \t]*.*\)$:file.input = '${NEW}':' f
```

Try to get inspired from it.

HTH!